# How to create a mock server for https in Citrus automation framework?

Tags: https, citrus-framework

I've been using Citrus as my Automation Framework and come across this problem.

I am calling a web service which invokes another server to get the access token through https call. I would like to hardcode the response for getToken with use of Static Endpoint Adapter.

My Code:

```
http().client(BPS_Create_Customer_PS_endpoint)
                .send()
                .post()
                .contentType("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8")
                .fork(true)
                .payload(new ClassPathResource("BPS_Create_Requests/valid.xml"));


        // HardCoded response withing context.xml will be sent first for getToken request
        // For Second call from BPS should come here and respond

        http().server(Server)
                .receive()
                .get()
                .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

        http().server(Server)
                .send()
                .response()
                .contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                .payload(new ClassPathResource("Output/valid.json"));

        http().server(BS_Customer)
                .receive()
                .post("/services/BS-Customer-PS")
                .contentType("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");

        http().server(BS_Customer)
                .send()
                .response()
                .withApplicationContext(applicationContext)
                .contentType("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action='urn:mediate'")
                .payload(new ClassPathResource("BS_Mock_Outputs/createCustomerResponse.xml"));

        http().client(BPS_Create_Customer_UW_PS_endpoint)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .payload(new ClassPathResource("BPS_Create_Responses/valid.xml"));
```

Context.xml File

```
 <citrus-http:client id="BPS_Create_Customer_PS_endpoint"
                  request-url="${Server_Endpoint}/services/BPS-Create-Customer-UW-PS.BPS-Create-Customer-UW-PSHttpSoap12Endpoint"
                    timeout="30000"/>


<citrus-http:server id="BS_Customer"
                  port="8085"
                  auto-start="true"/>


<citrus-http:server id="Server"
                    port="8092"
                    auto-start="true"/>

<citrus-http:server id="Token"
                    port="8091"
                    auto-start="true"
                    endpoint-adapter="getToken"/>


<citrus:static-response-adapter id="getToken">
    <citrus:payload>
        <![CDATA[]
        {
        "access_token": "00D0k000000Cp3S!ARIAQCFUdlJgqeZF_wh_Ifc6YOf7bHqnlRKN3l5ZNWXMLEqZk5lXqAogfKPZVx7E5UV9UKushYCzup7X",
        "instance_url": "https://ValidURL",
        "id": "https://ValidURL/id/00D023/0050k000000E3SqAAK",
        "token_type": "Bearer",
        "issued_at": "1494984553384",
        "signature": "t7VDcWe8oJDR/6ZzfllrOK2QI1OXg5S9OUoc="
        }
        ]]>
    </citrus:payload>
    <citrus:header>
        <citrus:element name="content-type" value="application/json"/>
        <citrus:element name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>
        <citrus:element name="content-security-policy" value="reflected-xss block;report-uri /_/ContentDomainCSPNoAuth?type=xss"/>
        <citrus:element name="content-Encoding" value="gzip"/>        
        <citrus:element name="Authorization" value="Bearer 0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42"/>
    </citrus:header>

</citrus:static-response-adapter>
```

Error:

> TID: [-1] [] [2017-05-17 12:33:27,726] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler} -  I/O error: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection? {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler}
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
>           at sun.security.ssl.EngineInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(EngineInputRecord.java:156)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:868)
>           at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
>           at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
>           at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
>           at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your token http server should use ssl connectors like this:

```
<citrus-http:server id="Token"
                    connector="sslConnector"
                    endpoint-adapter="getToken"
                    auto-start="true"/>

<bean id="sslConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"></bean>
  </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
            <property name="keyStorePath" value="/path/to/keystore.jks"/>
            <property name="keyStorePassword" value="secret"/>
          </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="http/1.1"/>
      </bean>
      <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
            <constructor-arg>
              <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
                <property name="secureScheme" value="https"/>
                <property name="securePort" value="8443"/>
              </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="customizers">
              <list>
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/>
              </list>
            </property>
          </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
  <property name="port" value="8443" />
</bean>
```

Comment: We are thinking of using Citrus for our testing framework. We have a microservice architecture and will need to doing service mocking. Even though the answer is shown as correct, it is no where close to the attempt. How would one normally be able to figure all that out? Is it in the documentation?

Comment: We are constantly improving the Citrus documentation. Questions like this are more related to configuration of Spring framework components. This is why we show these kind of usage scenarios in a special samples section: https://www.citrusframework.org/samples/https/

Comment: Missing documentation and unclear feature descriptions are located/fixed by us and the community this is part of the open source culture. This is how the Citrus project can constantly improve. So questions like this are very valuable to the framework.